# navbar style in Chrome and Firefox in OK but in IE i have problem

Tags: html, css, angular

my html code in here, in chrome and firefox, everything in OK but in Internet Explorer header style has been messed up.
I thought this is because of mdb-navbar, but I don't know the source of my problem

```
<mdb-navbar SideClass="navbar navbar-expand-lg header-card grey lighten-4 navbar-light mb-4"
            [containerInside]="false">
  <mdb-navbar-brand>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 user-info col-sm-12">
        <div class="data-column user-name">
          <app-text-block [Title]='"user "' [info]="currentUserName"></app-text-block>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7 medicalcenter-info col-sm-12 hidden-phone">
        <div class="col-12 data-column">
          <app-text-block [Title]='"med kind"' [info]="medicalCenter?.MedicalCenterKind.Caption"></app-text-block>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 data-column">
          <app-text-block [Title]='"med name"' [info]="consumerCorp?.Title"></app-text-block>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 datetime">
          <span>
            {{todayJalali}}
          </span>
          <span>
            {{timeNow}}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mdb-navbar-brand>
</mdb-navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get it display as a block and try.
You can easily do it using css properties Add "display:block" to your declaration.

Comment: in which of my tags?